# Can I have WebStorm keyboard shortcuts in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts, webstorm, hotkeys

I write both JS (in WebStorm) and Java (in IntelliJ). However, the navigation shortcuts in both applications are very different. Tab management (closing, opening etc) being the most frustrating example.

Is there an easy way to import WebStorm keyboard shortcuts into IntelliJ?

Comment: They use the same keymaps. It sounds like you are using different keymaps in each IDE. Go to `Settings/Preferences | Keymap` and see which one you are using.

Comment: @LazyOne Ah yes! One was on 'Mac OSX' and one on 'Mac OSX 10.5+'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They use the same keymaps.

It sounds like you are using different keymaps in each IDE. Go to `Settings/Preferences | Keymap` and see which one you are using. Then set both IDEs to use the same keymap.

**P.S.** Since you are on Mac then you should use `Mac OSX 10.5+` one.